# Angular @ViewChild(): ElementRef is undefined (HTML video element)

Tags: angular, video

I am having a problem that my @ViewChild('video') video!: ElementRef; is undefined.
I am having a page with embedded video. Video is fetched from API and it is .mp4 format. I need to set currentTime to my video, so it should not play from the beginning.

I tried also ngAfterViewInit() and it is the same, video is somehow not loaded yet even in ngAfterViewInit.

However I found a solution that it works, but it is with setTimeout and I don't want to use that, because this is not a proper solution I guess.

My code is:
HTML:

```
<main class="page" *ngIf="videoLoaded">
  <div class="bg-gray" *ngIf="isLoaded">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="video-div {{ slide.count == 0 ? 'full-width' : '' }}">
        <div class="video-parent">
          <video
            id="lecture-video"
            controls
            #video
          >
            <source [src]="videoUrl" />
          </video>
        </div>  
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner-parent" *ngIf="!isLoaded">
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  </div>
</main>
```

Typescript:

```
 private isVideoLoaded$!: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  @ViewChild('video') video!: ElementRef;

 constructor(
    ...
  ) {
    this.isVideoLoaded$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.videoLoadedSubs = this.isVideoLoaded$.subscribe((data: boolean) => {
      this.videoLoaded = data;
      console.log(data);
      if (this.videoLoaded) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.isPageLoaded = true;
          this.video.nativeElement.currentTime = 500;
        }, 100);
      }
    });

    this.videoApiSubs= this.videoService
      .getVideo(this.id)
      .subscribe((videoData: Video) => {
        this.videoData= videoData;
        this.videoUrl = this.videoData.video;

        this.lectureLoaded = true;
        this.isVideoLoaded$.next(true);
      });
  }
```

If I remove that setTimeout I get that video is undefined.. I don't know what even I can try anymore..

Comment: Try with `@ViewChild('video', {static: false}) video!: ElementRef;`

Comment: ViewChild references should never be accessed before view init, use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: Both of those suggestions doesn't work. I tried ngAfterViewInit before and it doesn't work, even if i try 'video', {static: false}.

Comment: Make sure that both `videoLoaded` and `isLoaded` are truthy before accessing the video element - If a `*ngIf` computes to `false`, the child elements are not rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `*ngIf`, the rendered template does not have the element `video` when `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` is executed. Try using `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` and using `ngAfterViewInit`.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of `*ngIf="videoLoaded"` and `*ngIf="isLoaded"`

the video element might not be loaded. You need to add `{ static: false }` like this:

```js
@ViewChild('video', { static: false }) video!: ElementRef;
```

Comment: What does `{ static: false }` dp if the `*ngIf` itself computes to `false`?

Comment: if `*ngIf`computes `false` it will never work of course ;) the video element must be rendered